# Is it possible to include / extend anchor from another .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration

I am trying to reuse anchor from one yaml file in another yaml file,

parent-gitlab-ci.yml

```
.basic_check1: &basic_check1
   script:
    - echo "basic check1"

.basic_check2: &basic_check2
   script:
    - echo "basic check2"
```

child-gitlab-ci.yml

```
include:
  - local: 'parent-gitlab-ci.yml'

stages:
  - test

job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - *basic_check1
    - *basic_check2
```

But I am getting error- 'This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: Unknown alias: basic_check1'. Is there any solution for this? I want to include script from two anchors. Tried using template job with before script as a hack but it doesn't solve my problem as I cant have two before scripts in a job to mimic two anchors like above.

Answer (score 3):

There are still large paragraphs in official documentation about yaml anchors... but this is obsolete. You ALWAYS have better alternatives (more concise and/or cross-files).

Here is one for your use case :

*.templates.gitlab-ci.yml*

```yaml
.basic_check1:
  script:
    - echo "basic check1"

.basic_check2:
  script:
    - echo "basic check2"
```

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```yaml
include:
  - .templates.gitlab-ci.yml

job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - !reference [.basic_check1, script]
    - !reference [.basic_check2, script]
```

Supposing you have more than 2 blocks of code to merge, else you could do just some extends and use before_script/script.

Answer (score 2):

> You can’t use YAML anchors across multiple files when using the include keyword. Anchors are only valid in the file they were defined in. To reuse configuration from different YAML files, use !reference tags or the extends keyword.

From:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use reuse anchors from other files using "extends". You could extend the whole of .basic_check1 with the following syntax:

```
include:
  - .templates.gitlab-ci.yml

job1:
  stage: test
  extends:
   - .basic_check1
```

with the compiled job1 being:

```
job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "basic check1"
```

Comment: That is not what we call (YAML) anchors.